# Proving a language is not context-free using the pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

I had a question regarding the use of the pumping lemma for a particular language I came across. I feel like I have almost solved it, but have gotten stuck on the last steps and wanted some advice. Here's the language in question:

$$L = \{a^nb^jc^k:\ k = jn\}$$

$\space$

Choose $w = a^mb^mc^{m^2}$. For $w_0 = uv^ixy^iz$, we can come up with a total of five cases:

1. $vxy$ consists of all $a$'s.

   Let's say $v = a^{k_1}$ and $y = a^{k_2}$. If we use $i = 0$, then
   $$w_0 = a^{m-k_1-k_2}b^mc^{m^2}$$
   Considering the original condition of the language of $k = jn$,
   $$m^2 = m(m - k_1 - k_2) = m^2 - m(k_1 + k_2)$$
   is satisfied only if $k_1 = k_2 = 0$, which gives us a contradiction because
   that would mean $v$ and $y$ are empty and goes against the principle of the
   pumping lemma which states that $|vy| \ge 1$.
2. $vxy$ consists of $a$'s and $b$'s.
   Let's say $v = a^{k_1}$ and $y = b^{k_2}$. The same principle applies as case 1.
3. $vxy$ consists of all $b$'s. Same as previous cases.
4. $vxy$ consists of all $c$'s. Again, essentially the same principles may be used as previously.

The only case that I've been having trouble proving is the last one, where

5. $vxy$ consists of $b$'s and $c$'s.
   Let's again say $v = b^{k_1}$ and $y = c^{k_2}$. For $i = 0$,
   $$w_0 = a^mb^{m - k_1}c^{m^2 - k_2}$$
   $$m^2 - k_2 = m(m - k_1) = m^2 - mk_1\ ?$$

I've been having trouble determining whether or not the last condition of $k_2 = mk_1$ holds or not. Could anybody give me some tips or advice?

Thank you.

Comment: Recall that the pumping lemma also requires that $|vxy|\le m$.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment. I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but would that mean that $k_2 \ne mk_1$ because $m \ne 0$ and $m \gt k_1, k_2$, and therefore the last case is also a contradiction?

Comment: I think this is what Hendrik ment. If you look at the extreme case: If $k_1 = 1$ you would have to remove $m$ $c$s with pumping number $0$ hence $k_2 = m$ but then $m+1 = k_1 + k_2 \leq |vxy| \leq m$, a contradiction. For $k_1 > 1$ the argument is the same as you have to increase $k_2$, too.

Comment: Thanks @PHPNick . I think I had an equivalent reasoning $|vxu| \ge k_1+k_2 = (m+1) k_1 \ge m+1 > m$ since $k_1 \ge 1$, working from the equality $k_2=mk_1$. Feel free to write a full answer, if you have time.

Comment: Thanks @HendrikJan and PHPNick for clearing it up for me :)